# bash for loop only return last value xtimes of xlength of arra

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a file with IDs such as below:

```
A
D
E
```

And I have a second file with the same IDs and extra info that I need:

```
A    50     G25T1    7.24      298
B    20     G234T2   8.3       80
C    5      G1I1     5.2       909
D    500    G458T3   0.4       79
E    321    G46I2    45.8      901
```

I want to output the third column of the second file by selecting the first column of the second file using the ids from first file:

```
G25T1
G458T3
G46I2
```

The issue I have is while the for loop runs, the output is as follows:

```
G46I2
G46I2
G46I2
```

Here is my code:

```
a=0; IFS=$'\r\n' command eval 'ids=($(awk '{print$1}' shared_single_copies.txt | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]//g'))'; for id in "${ids[@]}"; do a=$(($a+1)); echo $a' '"$id"; awk '{$1=="${id}"} END {print $3}' run_Busco_A1/A1_single_copy_ids.txt >> A1_genes_sc_Buscos.txt; done
```

Comment: I've improved the formatting for the data part of your question. Please improve the formatting of your code: one line is unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is way too complicated. Try one of these solutions: "file1" contains the ids, "file2" contains the extra info:

```
$ join -o 2.3 file1 file2
G25T1
G458T3
G46I2
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {id[$1]; next} $1 in id {print $3}' file1 file2
G25T1
G458T3
G46I2
```

For more help about `join`, check the man page.
For more help about `awk`, start with the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) info page.

Answer (score 1):

@glenn jackman's answer was by far the most succinct and elegant imo. If you want to use  loops, though, then this can work:

```
#!/bin/bash

# if output file already exists, clear it so we don't 
# inadvertently duplicate data:
> A1_genes_sc_Buscos.txt

while read -r selector
do
  while read -r c1 c2 c3 garbage
  do
    [[ "$c1" = "$selector" ]] && echo "$c3" >> A1_genes_sc_Buscos.txt
  done < run_Busco_A1/A1_single_copy_ids.txt
done < shared_single_copies.txt
```

That should work for your use-case provided the formatting is valid between what you gave as input and your real files.

Comment: You can simplify this by putting `> A1_genes_sc_Buscos.txt` after the final `done`, and removing the other writes to it.